# Find users residing between a specified distance (using user's zipcode)

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, actionscript

Is there a way to find the radial distance using the zipcode?

My task is to search the all the users residing with in a specified distance. I know the zipcodes of the users.

Eg, users between 25 miles from the current location.

I have other search categories, for which i am using mysql queries. I am unable to figure anything out for the distance issue.

My backend is in php
and frontend in Flex.

The best option for me would be something like that of www.zip-codes.com/zip-code-radius-finder.asp. ie, if I should be able to get all the zip-codes available in the specified radial distance. So i can compare this zip-codes to the users zip-codes in my database. And select the ones with a match.

Please help me out with this.
Zeeshan

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349763/mysql-php-zip-code-comparison-specifically-distance/2349787#2349787

Comment: What's the bounty for - didn't Eric's suggestion work? You'll either need to geocode all of the users' zipcodes then search e.g. using the formula stillstanding linked to, or you'll need to get geocoded data for all zipcodes, search for all zipcodes within 25 miles then search your database for users in those codes. Which way round will depend on the relative numbers of users and zipcodes, but unless you can get an all-codes dataset I suspect you'll want a join table where map all ZIPs not yet seen to lat/long via Google Maps and then join against that for searching.

Comment: Zip Code Radius Finder: it sounds like you should buy their $40 dataset then from the links on the left?

Answer (score 8):

I accomplished something similar using the free Google Maps API - which may be good enough to use for your needs as well

http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2006/06/geocoding-at-last.html - brief post on the subject (from 2006)

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html - Google Maps API home

Answer (score 6):

Postcodes don't map directly to a distance to each other. You will have to acquire postcode & lat/long data, look up the postcodes in there, and compare the distance between the lat/long coordinates. Depending on the locality free data may be available, but it's very common to buy such a table, or subscribe to a possibly paid webservice which does the translation of postcode to lat/long or neighboring postcodes for you.

Answer (score 2):

[Google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=php+find+radius+from+postal+code&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) found some good hits:

- http://www.kevinbradwick.co.uk/2010/01/calculating-the-radius-of-a-coordinate-using-php/
- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3867-PHP-Lookup-United-States-zip-codes-in-a-MySQL-database.html

Answer (score 2):

**You can do all of this with just the database**

1. Download a free geocoded database of US zipcodes ([like this one](http://www.lustforge.com/2011/07/20/really-free-zipcode-database-download/))
2. Drop them into your database
3. Write a simple sql function to compare two zips (i.e. ZIP_DIST(zip1,zip2) )
4. Search against your list of peoples' zips and sort by the above function comparing everyone's zips to your target zip.
5. Finally return the N closest values.

This way everything is run and cached at your MySQL layer. No API's needed.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can implement some of code from Google API, but [here](http://depositfiles.com/files/34mgbsaa5) is a little project, I've wrote for you, and its look like below:
[image: btw i got one of services from google output like free-zipcode-maps.com/tools/zipcoderadius/extractzips2.cgi?Zip_Code=90503&Miles=30]

here is code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:HTTPService id="service" resultFormat="text" result="service_resultHandler(event)" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.toString())"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:HGroup width="100%" 
              horizontalAlign="center"
              verticalAlign="middle"
              textAlign="center">
        <s:Label text="ZIP code"/>
        <s:TextInput id="zip" text="90503"/>
        <s:Label text="Radius in miles"/>
        <s:TextInput id="miles" text="5"/>
        <s:Button label="GO!" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:HGroup>
    <mx:DataGrid id="dg" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="zip" headerText="ZIP Code"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="distance" headerText="{'Distance in Miles from '+zip.text}"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="city" headerText="City"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="state" headerText="State"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            [Bindable]
            public var result:Array=new Array();

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                service.url="http://free-zipcode-maps.com/tools/zipcoderadius/extractzips2.cgi?Zip_Code="+zip.text+"&Miles="+miles.text;
                service.send();             
            }

            protected function service_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {   
                //<textarea name="download" cols=65 rows=20>
                //ZIP Code  Distance in Miles from 90503    City    State
                //</textarea>
                var res:String=event.result.toString();
                var startString:String="ZIP Code    Distance in Miles from "+zip.text+" City    State";
                var start:int=res.search(startString)+startString.length+1;
                var end:int=res.search('</textarea>')-1;
                res=res.substring(start,end);

                var rows:Array=res.split("\n");             
                for each(var row:String in rows)
                {
                    var r:Array=row.split("\t");
                    result.push({zip:r[0],distance:r[1],city:r[2],state:r[3]});
                }

                dg.dataProvider=new ArrayCollection(result);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


</s:Application>
```